# How to download an audio file from a web site on iOS?

Tags: audio, web-browsing, web-browser

Is there a way to download an audio file, such as a mp3-file or a Quicktime-file from the iOS Safari browser to the device so I could listen to it later when I'm offline? Is there a way I should program the web site to make this possible?

I'm *not* looking for an additional app to help me achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  This is not possible at this time without using a third party app. I use [GoodReader](http://www.goodiware.com/goodreader.html) for this—and other—tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the appstore and look for free music downloading apps. There's plenty of options

Answer (score 0):

That was my big problem but I found two apps in App Store that helped me. For IOS.

1. “Bolt Browser and Document “ app at first time you must download a web page pdf or html in app and after it always you click in any web audio it say to download or play, wonderful.
2. “Browser & Offline File Storage” app it is very wonderful in any web page only click in + (+ is in app screen) and then it show you all hidden links in that page audio/image/etc all links for you and you can click one or more links and then click "OR" to download your links file.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Just a piece of friendly advice - you're more likely to get views and up votes if you take the time to format your answer so that it's readable, provide links to off site resources (like to the apps you recommend) and use proper grammar.  "U" and "ur" and ***not*** acceptable abbreviations for "you" and "your."  See [How to write a good answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for tips on writing an answer that will get attention and ultimately up voted.